# How do I reorder photos in a shared album on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I used to be able to just edit an album and drag photos about to reorder them. Now, whenever I click on a photo, it just wants to tag it rather than let me drag it.

How can I reorder the photos in a shared album?

(This may only be an issue with newly created albums.)